# Float:left not working on a dynamic content div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a base div where I can copy it as many times as I need for when I want to add new content to my website. So the Html looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
<p class="date">17/03/1014</p>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p class="postText">djdfkjdfssdfldfskjldfskjldfskjldsfkjldsfjkldsjkldjkl 
</p>
</div>
<div class="postImage"><img src="images/car.jpg" width="300" alt="car></div>
```

Then my css looks like this:

```
   .post{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#CCC;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;


    /*CSS3*/
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;

    -webkit-outline: 1px dashed #000000;
    -moz-outline: 1px dashed #000000;
    outline: 1px dashed #000000;

    -webkit-outline-offset: -5px;
    -moz-outline-offset: -5px;
    outline-offset: -5px;
    behavior:url(PIE.htc);


}

.post p.postText {
    width:500px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}


.post p.date{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:10px;

}

.postImage {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

If you test it, the image doesn't float on the right of the text, but instead is below it. Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: Content above a float does not wrap around that float. Your content needs to be below your float in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start simple - get your positioning correct first, then add in the padding, borders, /*CSS3*/ stuff.  http://jsfiddle.net/bEECn/

There are many ways to accomplish this, but I think wrapping your textual content in a container and floating that may be the most straight forward for you.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <p class="date">17/03/1014</p>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p class="postText">djdfkjdfssdfldfskjldfskjldfskjldsfkjldsfjkldsjkldjkl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="postImage">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" width="300" alt="car" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, this simple CSS:

```
.content-wrap, .postImage {
    float: left;
}
```

From there, you can add your additional styles.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your exact HTML, you have several errors. Not sure if that will completely fix your problem, but you need to fix your HTML either way.

```
<div class="post">
    <p class="date">17/03/1014</p> <!-- Was </div> -->
    <h1>Hello World!</h1> <!-- Was </div> -->
    <p class="postText">djdfkjdfssdfldfskjldfskjldfskjldsfkjldsfjkldsjkldjkl</p>
</div> <!-- Was missing -->

<div class="postImage">
    <img src="images/car.jpg" width="300" alt="car>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I passed the code to here wrong. It's not like that in my real code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSFiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/FRDKL/

I found allot of HTML errors for example:

```
<img src="images/car.jpg" width="300" alt="car>
```

U forgot an " at the end of your ALT. I hope this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/FRDKL/

Comment: You resolved the errors, but not the original question - making it float